# while opening the project on the eclispe it showing the following eror

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest

Application package 'AndroidManifest.xml' must have a minimum of 2 segments.

ABC
    
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    
    
        Apache Cordova Team

Comment: 1) This is related to your own setup.
2) Post the AndroidManifest.xml
3) No idea what the second paragraph states? Mind rephrasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Application package 'AndroidManifest.xml' must have a minimum of 2 segments.

Means:-
What is means is the package declaration in your manifest must have at least two segments, or portions separated by a period (.). Instead of just saying package="save_money", change it to package="com.save_money". That should remove your error. Likewise, everywhere you specify the name of an activity, you also need to update it there. Alternatively, you can just say .MyActivityName and eclipse will automatically plug in your package name before the (.) and will change it to com.save_money.MyActivityName.

2.[Read here about configuration](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/config_ref_index.md.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: tnkxx pblm is been sloved